# QJSEngine deletes my QObject, how to change ownership after QJSEngine::newQObject?

Tags: c++, qt, qjsengine

Trying to perform small script with subclassed QObject as parameter.

```
QJSEngine jsEngine;
QJSValue arg = jsEngine.newQObject(child); // Child it's subclassed QObject
QJSValue function = jsEngine.evaluate(m_childRestriction);

QJSValue result = function.call(QJSValueList() << arg);
```

On destroying jsEngine, it calls delete for my child object (as newQObject creates it with JavaScriptOwnership). How to avoid it, how to change ownership for arg?

Script is simple:

```
function(device) { 
    return device.m_place >=0 && device.m_place < 16; 
}
```

**UPD:**
It is possible to call `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(child, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);` for the object as it is the static function. It just not clear from the help. Think it is suppose to be in `QJSEngine` also.

Comment: You might try adding `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(this, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);` to the constructor for your object.  Not sure if it applies to your case, but it does prevent Qml from deleting our objects.

Comment: I don't have QQmlEngine, it is inherits QJSEngine.

Comment: You still can use the method that @RetiredNinja mentioned. It's in the same Qt module (so you will always have it available) and it's even used internally by `QJSEngine`! It's actually used by `QJSEngine` to set the ownership of the object to JavaScript. You can call it afterwards like @RetiredNinja said to make it owned back by CPP.

Comment: Oh yes, It is a static function... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to call QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(child, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership); for the object as it is the static function. It just not clear from the help. Think it is suppose to be in QJSEngine also.